# How to use argparse during runtime to conditionally get further input?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a little script with a parent parser that accepts either a `create` or `run` argument.

In the former case, I want to get more information from the user, but I want to get it piecemeal so they don't have to enter in a 15-argument string at the outset. I can create my next parser but when I pass it a string from `raw_input()` each character is being treated as an argument which leads me to believe I am doing this wrong:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands', help='additional help')

create_parser = subparsers.add_parser('create')
create_parser.set_defaults(func=create)

run_parser = subparsers.add_parser('run')
run_parser.set_defaults(func=run)

def create():
    author_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    author_parse.add_argument('name', type=str, nargs=2)
    auth_args = auth_parse.parse_args(raw_input("Provide your first and last name:"))


   # >> myprogram run
   # >> Provide your first and last name:
   # >> john smith
   # >> error: unrecognized arguments: h n S m i t h
```

EDIT: For those wondering why I'm not just using `raw_input()` it's because I am going to go through several rounds of getting further information from the user and want to leverage argparse's formidable ability to intelligently manage input rather than writing it all myself. For example, integers would not be an acceptable response to "What is  your first and last name?".

`raw_input()` is the only way I'm aware of to get a response from the user *during runtime*, and this is the only reason I've called it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing and why you wouldn't just store the value from raw input directly

Comment: Well as stated in the question, there's going to be several rounds of further-information getting, and I'd like to leverage argparse's ability to offer help text, format incoming vars, etc.. In the current example, if someone passes in "1234" "-65" I'd like to not accept either of these as first or last names.

Comment: right just say name = raw_input("Provide your first and last name:"). I don't understand why you are using argparse. I think your problem is with nargs=2 but I am not sure. That is looking for two characters I believe.

Comment: @aplassard https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argparse.parse_args()` takes an iterable of strings; you are passing a single string. Try

```
def create():
    author_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    author_parse.add_argument('name', type=str, nargs=2)
    name = raw_input("Provide your first and last name: ")
    auth_args = auth_parse.parse_args(name.split())
```

A string, being iterable itself, is treated like a list of the characters in the string. That is,

```
auth_parse.parse_args("John Smith")
```

produces the same result as

```
auth_parse.parse_args(["J", "o", "h", "n", " ", "S", "m", "i", "t", "h"])
```

Comment: Yes, the default to `parse_args` is `sys.argv[1:]`, a list of strings.  A typical test input looks like `parse_args(['one','two'])`. The code that treats the input as an iterable is a couple of layers down the stack, in a line that reads: `arg_strings_iter = iter(arg_strings)`.